Jinja2 (flask): How to pass blocks to a macro?
I'm implementing a python flask webapp and I'm trying to write a macro to which I want to pass three blocks of html-code, but couldn't get it run.
I found a simple example on making use of jinja with fastapi here: https://www.slingacademy.com/article/fastapi-how-to-use-macros-in-jinja-templates/?utm_content=cmp-true
I expected that it works, but I couldn't get it run. I tried it and got the error message: "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: block 'content' defined twice".
{% macro panel(title, class='panel') %}
<div class="{{ class }}">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% call(panel, title='My Panel') %}
{% block content %}
  <p>This is a panel content.</p>
{% endblock %}
{% endcall %}

Should this example work or is there a bug in the jinja2 template? Is there an alternative/better way to pass html-code blocks to a macro? I recognized the "caller" approach, but I think it only works with one code block, right?
Thank you!
Kind regards,
Jerome
EDIT
It looks like the example is to much simplified. I would like to pass 2 or 3 html or even jinja code blocks to the macro. The background is that I want to simplify the use of Bootstrap Accordion which I want to use multiple times in same way.
Extending the example it's more like this:
{% macro panel(title, class='panel') %}
<div class="{{ class }}">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  {% block content1 %}{% endblock %}
   <!-- Do some other stuff in between. -->
  {% block content2 %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% call(panel, title='My Panel') %}
{% block content1 %}
  <p>This is a panel content.</p>
{% endblock %}
{% block content2 %}
  <p>This is the detailed panel content.</p>
{% endblock %}
{% endcall %}

EDIT 2
Based on the answer and hints of @Detlef, somehow I got the example working with template inheritance, see below. Anyhow, I use the call caller concept as it's the more obvious way to do.
mymacro.j2:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
{% macro panel(title, class='panel') %}
<div class="{{ class }}">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    {% block content1 %}{% endblock %}
    <h3> Stuff in between. </h3>
    {% block content2 %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% block macrocall %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

main.j2:
{% extends "mymacro.j2" %}

{% block content1 %}
<p>Panel content1.</p>
{% endblock %}
{% block content2 %}
<p>This is content2.</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block macrocall %}
{{ panel(title='My Panel') }}
{% endblock %}


The command caller() gives you the option of dynamically embedding code in the macro that was called with call(). If you assign a variable name in call() and pass an attribute to caller(), this can also be used with the defined variable name in the embedded code.
You can find the documentation here.
{% macro panel(title, class_='panel') %}
<div class="{{ class_ }}">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    {{ caller() }}
</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% call() panel(title='My Panel') %}
    <p>This is a panel content.</p>
{% endcall %}

The code passed is for the respective call.
As long as the block names remain unique within the template, you can also use multiple nested blocks within the macro call.
{% call() panel(title='My Panel') %}
    {% block content1 %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content2 %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endcall %}


A simple example implementation of a macro for a bootstrap accordion.
{% macro bs_accordion(items) %}
    <div class="accordion {{ kwargs.class_ }}" id="{{ kwargs.id }}">
        {% for k,v in items.items() -%}
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header">
                <button 
                    class="accordion-button {% if not loop.first %}collapsed{% endif %}" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-bs-target="#collapse-{{ loop.index }}" 
                    aria-expanded="{{ loop.first | lower }}" 
                    aria-controls="collapse-{{ loop.index }}"
                >{{ k }}</button>
            </h2>
            <div 
                id="collapse-{{ loop.index }}" 
                class="accordion-collapse collapse {% if loop.first %}show{% endif %}" 
                data-bs-parent="#{{ kwargs.id }}"
            >
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    {{ caller(v) }}
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link 
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container my-4">
    {% set items = { 
            'My Panel 1': ['This is the first panel.', 'This is the detailed panel content.'], 
            'My Panel 2': {'Description': 'This is the second panel.', 'Details': 'This is the detailed panel content.'}, 
            'My Panel 3': 'This is the third panel.', 
        } 
    %}

    {% call(content) bs_accordion(items, id='accordionExample') %}
        {% if content is string -%}
            {{ content }}
        {% elif content is mapping -%}
            <dl>
            {% for k,v in content.items() -%}
                <dt>{{ k }}</dt>
                <dd>{{ v }}</dd>
                {% if not loop.last -%}
                <!-- Do some other stuff in between. -->
                {% endif -%}
            {% endfor -%}
            </dl>
        {% elif content is sequence -%}
            {% for item in content -%}
                <p>{{ item }}</p>
                {% if not loop.last -%}
                <!-- Do some other stuff in between. -->
                {% endif -%}
            {% endfor -%}
        {% endif -%}
    {% endcall %}
    </main>

    <script 
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>


Hi! I've added an extended example in my question. If I would like to pass only one "block" of html or jinja code I understood it's possible with the call-caller approach. Would it also be applicable in cases where I want to pass more than one code-block?

I have expanded my answer and think your approach should work as long as the conditions mentioned are met. That is, the block identifiers are unique within the template.

Thank you. Unfortunately, still I can't get it working with the "block". Running the first example, which I put in my question, I still get: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: block 'content' defined twice
Did you try the example? Did you implement the macro the same way I did? Thanks

Yes, I tested the example. The error message indicates that a block with the name "content" is duplicated. A block is a definition to extend a template. See template inheritance. The block in the parent template is replaced by the block of the same name in the child template. In my case, the macro as specified above and its call are implemented in the parent template and the blocks are replaced by a child template.

@Jerome I have expanded my answer to include a possible implementation of a bootstrap accordion. Perhaps the example will help you get closer to a solution. I don't think that using blocks will help you.

With your extended example, now I understood. So far, I didn't completely understand the concept of call and caller. With your example now I see that it's possible to pass different string/code to the macro based on the argument of 'call' (in this case called 'content').
Additionally, with your hint on the template inheritance I was abled to get it run somehow.  For completeness, I will share the code in an additional answer.
Anyhow, I will go for the call-concept as it's the more obvious way to do.
Thanks a lot for your help.
